# brew\homebrew use ruby api and not its cli api

Tags: ruby, homebrew

rather than using the brew through the command line, i would like to use its api in ruby.

for instance, rather than executing `brew info --json wget` in the command line, use brew within a [ruby code like `Brew.info("wget")`](https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Cask/Cmd/Info.html#info-class_method) (i am familiar with the message that appears in the ruby doc) without implementing a ruby wrapper for shelling out brew cli.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: @HolgerJust don't know how to start, where i need to use brew source code directly, whether there is any rubygem (i didn't find any in rubygems.org), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no homebrew SDK for any language, so you might have to wrap the command line to develop something. :(